# Why is there /etc and ~/.config? Why is the global config called "etc" yet the user's config stuff is called ".config"?

Tags: etc

Why is there `/etc` and `~/.config`? Why is the global config called "etc" yet the user's config stuff is called ".config"?

Comment: One was created 40 years ago, the other much more recently. They were created by different people who had different ideas about naming. Some applications use neither location.

Comment: The etc stands for **editable text configuration**.

Answer (score 1):

Just review definition of each files:

1. The `/etc` hierarchy contains configuration files. A "configuration file" is a local file used to control the operation of a program; it must be static and cannot be an executable binary.
2. `$HOME/.config` is where per-user configuration files go if there is no `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`

Based on [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313001): "The idea is that per-user files can be (amongst quite a lot of other things) application data files (machine-specific or roaming), application configuration files, cached files, and temporary files, and applications place them in subtrees rooted at these particular directories."

More Reading:

1. [Host-specific system configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313001)
2. [configuration ethics (esthetics): /etc vs $HOME](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313001)
3. [Understanding home configuration file locations: ~/, ~/.config/ and ~/.local/share/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312988/understanding-home-configuration-file-locations-config-and-local-sha)

Answer (score 0):

***.config*** is a convention defined in https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html which is used for to keep user spesific config files (new way), before that general usage is every app kepps their  config files in their ***~.APP_NAME*** folder (old way)

***/etc*** is a unix spesification which used to keep system-wide config files. https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/etc.html